# Qt Creator - Where is the Right Sidebar in Debug View?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, sidebar

For *Qt Creator* (4.4.0 in my case):

Is there a compelling reason for the fact that the *Right Sidebar* is not available in the *Debug* view?

In my particular case I prefer to have the *Project View* on the right side like in all the other IDE's that I'm using.

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A left and right sidebar are available in most Qt Creator modes. The
>   availability of the sidebars and their contents **depend** on the mode.
>
> In the Edit mode, you can use the sidebars to browse projects, files,
>   and bookmarks, and to view the class hierarchy.

NOT possible to have right [sidebar](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html#browsing-project-contents) in debug mode.

In `Edit mode` you have left & right sideBars.

In `Debug mode` you have only left sideBar.

In `Welcome`, `Project`, `Help` no sideBar.

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html#browsing-project-contents